# How to get 3d cursor location through script in blender 2.8?

Tags: scripting, 3d-cursor

I have seen this question for some older versions of blender. But I can't figure out what's the way in 2.8. Someone, please help. I've been looking at all the corners of the API documentation I can't find anything.

code:

```
import bpy

print(
print("""-------------------------------------\n
        script_003.py started\n
        -------------------------------------""")
#- -------------------------------------

# print 3D cursor location

loc = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
print(loc)

print("""-------------------------------------\ns
        script_003.py ended\n
        -------------------------------------""")
```

output:
  File "E:\chandan\Work\blender-2.8\Development\Addons\practice_001.blend\Script_003.py", line 11
    loc = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location: :-1

Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cursor-location-as-scene-attribute/6110

Comment: if i type bpy.context.scene.cursor.location it works. But if i try to print it in a script its not working. I have imported bpy.

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: yes. SyntaxError: invalid syntax. one sec I'll put the code in the description.

Comment: the third line: "print(" alone. Remove that

Comment: oops, I'm sorry. that was so silly of me. I totally overlooked that